# Adding labels to react-select breaks functionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-select

I have have created a [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/) that used [react-select](https://react-select.com/home). My input field component allows me to choose a select option OR create a new option by typing into the input/select box. Example of this working well codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/o49kjl09j9

The next part of my component is to group the options by the data label - you will see how this works via this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/k5pyr75xor

The issue is after I have applied my changes for the groups to work I can no longer type a new option in my select/input box. Not sure how to fix the error. I've changed how the data is structured coming in to create the groups but can't seem to implement the below code into my sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/k5pyr75xor.

UPDATE: The issue is that the created value does not have a label - but I would add a default label to created options. e.g. "Custom"

This is the code that the react-select docs recommend without success:

```
const formatGroupLabel = data => (
  <div style={groupStyles}>
    <span>{data.label}</span>
    <span style={groupBadgeStyles}>{data.options.length}</span>
  </div>
);

export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={colourOptions[1]}
    options={groupedOptions}
    formatGroupLabel={formatGroupLabel}
  />
);
```

Any assistance would be appreciated here.

UPDATE: Know issue here and solution - https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/2659

I need help implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dive into the issue.

The solution was to write your own isValidNewOption to replace the builtin and pass it as a property to the creatable select because Using the options from http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ "Numeric Values" breaks it cause .toLowerCase() doesn't work on numbers

Fixed example: https://codesandbox.io/s/p72l42pz30

```
  isValidNewOption = (inputValue, selectValue, selectOptions) => {
    if (
      inputValue.trim().length === 0 ||
      selectOptions.find(option => option.name === inputValue)
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```

and adding this to the select:

```
isValidNewOption={this.isValidNewOption}
```